# What is the problem? Am I doing wrong? is there any other way of doing this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**This is my code and the error I am getting is in attached picture what is the error in my code. The Purpose of my code is that while typing in Textinput if the length of passcode is less than 10 a message should be displayed that length is less than 10 and when length become greater than 10 message will disappear[image]**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text,View,Button,TextInput} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  return (
    <View>
    <Text> Nam likhay Apna</Text>
      <TextInput
      secureTextEntry={true}
      style = {styles.inp}
      autoCapitalize = "none"
      autoCorrect = {false}
      value = {name}
      onChangeText = {newValue => setName(newValue)}
      />
    if({name}.length < 10){
        console.log('Password should be greater than 10 enteries')
    }
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inp:{
        margin:15,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 2 
    }
});
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Example: [ExpoSnack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/eager-ice-cream)**

[image]

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={{ marginHorizontal: 15 }}> Nam likhay Apna</Text>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={true}
        style={styles.inp}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCorrect={false}
        value={name}
        onChangeText={(newValue) => {
          setName(newValue);
          if (name.length < 10) {
            console.log('Password should be greater than 10 enteries');
          }
        }}
      />
      <Text style={{ color: name.length < 10 ? 'red' : 'green', marginHorizontal: 15 }}>
        {name.length < 10
          ? 'Password should be greater than 10 enteries'
          : 'Correct Password'}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inp: {
    margin: 15,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
});
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `name.length` instead of `{name}.length`